# Bounding box orientation

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, robotics

I have used a bounding box to get the pair of 4-points around an object after RANSAC and conditional outlier removal during the segmentation and filtration process.  After computing the 8 corner points of the bounding box, I have used 2 of them (front below) to localize the robot. for e.g following is a visual of the extracted object with the corner-points I intend to use

[image]

The problem is if the object is straight like above the robot moves correctly almost in the middle but if the object is tilted the robot moves more on the right or left depending on which side it is tilted for example

[image]

After analysis it seems that bounding box points are not exactly but with a offset on the object. What can be helpful in this situation ?

-adding a manual offset on the corner points

-adjusting segmentation thresholds

-Possible to use surface normal or angle information from these points

anyother possibility

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you tilt the object, the point of the object corner that closer to you gives more precise information than the other point. And if you can take angle information, find the surface normal and then calculate the angle between the vector or line you draw between two points that you got initially and the normal vector. And try change the point according to the result you got, in the area of your offset that the normal and our vector will be 90 to each other.

For example you know the normal vector and you have two points (x1,y1), (x2,y2). draw a vector between these two points, calculate the angle between this vector and normal. If the angle comes like 85 degrees. Manipulate (x2,y2) to get 90 degrees. It is like you hold a vector from it's start point and playing with it's direction. Because we assume that our starting point is precise.

Comment: I totally agree with you. If I understand you correctly                                                                                       1) Finding vector in between 2 corner points                                                                 2) Estimating normal on these 2 corner points                                                                 3) If (angle in between both vectors is less than 90° or greater than 90°)                       4) How we can manipulate (x2,y2) to get 90 degrees. ?

Comment: It becomes a plane. Normal vector and the vector that we created. On this plane a vector can rotate only clockwise or counterclockwise. Try in one direction first rotate it so small. Calculate the angle if it is in correct direction continue. But if the error increases then change the direction. For example if you have a vector <2,2> in x y plane. Test first <2,0> if the angle becomes what you want its okay if not go to <0,2>. But increase numbers little. Go to point with multiple steps. For example put your sensitive like +-0.05.

Comment: Can you please mention any example code from PCL or OpenCV tutorial as well.

Comment: its not about programming language. Lets say you have a function that finds angle between two vector. and find the plane that contains the normal vector and the vector we created. Lets say we have findAngle(V1,V2) that returns 69 degrees. then change (x2,y2) then again findAngle(V1,V2) lets say it became 70 so continue rotating the vector in the same direction. its basic while loop and if statements. if previous findAngle() > current findAngle() continue increasing or decreasing. while(findAngle() > 89 && findAngle() < 91). But you should rotate in the same plane. that is all i can say now.